# 'Cache-Control&ETag in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have an app thats made on Angular2 and when I run a speed page test with pagespeed tool. I get an issue with leverage browser caching and it says to cache some of my resources as I'm making too many requests even though these resources are stored locally with the app.

when i go into details of leverage browser caching.They recommended below:
1-Cache-Control
2-ETag

Can anyone please help me to explain how can we implement Cache-Control&ETag in Angular2.

Answer (score 0):

> 'Cache-Control&ETag in Angular2.'

The headers you've mentioned are not angular-related. They should be populated by your HTTP server used to serve static files.

One of the ways to solve it on client-side, since its an angular-tagged topic is to create a manifest file like described here: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/